# Using dynamic identity providers with Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, okta, idp

I have a requirement to build a web app that connects to a customer's API (authenticated as the user using the web app). This same web app will need to connect to our own internal API which is authenticated with B2C.

The problem is that each customer has their own authentication server (always Okta) and so I couldn't add an IDP for each customer in a custom policy because I'd have to add thousands and continue to add them.

Is there a way to get IDP configuration programmatically so that I can look up the correct Okta instance?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had limited chance to set up the above scenario and test in lab.

Add the app in Okta and set the below parameters, instead of adding app in AAD.

Login redirect URI: https://{yourb2ctenantname}.b2clogin.com/{yourb2ctenantname}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

Change the following settings in the B2C Claims provider
Okta OpenId Connect Settings in B2C Policy:

ProviderName: https://{yourOktaTenant}/oauth2/default

METADATA: https://{yourOktaTenant}/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration

Reference Link: Use below link for custom policies in B2C:

https://github.com/mleziva/azure-b2c-okta-custom-policy

Comment: configure external authentication through pull or push
pull - we will accept something (like token / some ids, companyId ...  ) in header and our program get activated respective external authentication program
push - we have to manage while deployment time/ databased saved configuration for respective company
Note : 
1. IAppBuilder - Run, Use, Map and MapWhen extension method may be used to make loosely couple at some extent.
2.  Design with Open and Close principle